# How to delete a list of griddb databases according to conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, nosql, griddb

I have a list of databases I want to drop under a certain condition. I know GridDB SQL is not like Python
where you can write commands under a condition block. But I would like to know if I can delete
databases that have been updated only in the last two years.
Suppose I have 32 databases, or more, I want to delete the old databases with an SQL command similar
to the one below, if possible:

```sql
// Condition
 DROP DATABASE database;
```

or using Pandas, in Python:

```py
sql_statement = ('DROP DATABASE database')
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_statement, cont)
```

Maybe `database` is from a generator or something. How can I go about that?
I am using GridDB Python client on my Ubuntu machine. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't know GridDB but if you have some column to keep date when data was added/created/updated then first you would have to check it with normal `SELECT ... ORDER BY ...`.

Comment: as I know SQL allows only one condition - `IF EXISTS`